# List all tags within a module in CVS in CLI

Tags: cvs, cmd, version-control, tags

Is it possible to get a list of all generated tags for a given module in CVS?

I can use

```
cvs status -v FILE
```

but it shows too much information that I just don't need. I can use some gui utilities that show me only the tag names (Eclipse is one of them), how do they do it? You need to do some "hacks" or are just parameters I'm unaware of?

I would like to know if there's a command that would show me just something like this on terminal:

```
TAG1
TAG2
TAG3
TAG4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a script you can copy here:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ninja/List+CVS+Tags

Seems a shame this isn't 'core' functionality.

Comment: codehaus is gone... but the page still show's up in the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20121116021038/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ninja/List+CVS+Tags

Answer (score 7):

In bash

cvs -q status -R -v | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u

or

cvs -q status -v FILE | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u