# How to tell the most recent cvs version?

Tags: version-control, tags, cvs

I would like to know the latest cvs tag name of my project,

Is "tag" the same thing with "version"? If yes, how can I know which is the most recent tag in my project?

I do the following to check out the latest version of my project:

```
cvs co -d new_version my_project
```

So, which tag does above check out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag isn't the same than version, and you cannot determine the creation date of a tag, as mentioned in "[How to get a list of tags created in CVS repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6184269/6309)".
That answer gives a script to approximate the date of the tag.

And you can list all the tags, as mentioned in "[List all tags within a module in CVS in CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8897045/6309)".

Combining the two, you should be able to determine the most recent tags, compared to the one you just checked out.

Comment: @alwbtc you don't: http://stackoverflow.com/a/955468/6309. See cvs log a a file: http://www.tigris.org/nonav/scdocs/ddUsingCVS_command-line.html